# How to use eth0 hardware mac address for bond interface?

Tags: ubuntu, bonding

We are running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. We are using bonding in the network interfaces file. After rebooting the server, bond0 interface always takes a new mac address. How to make the bond0 interface use the eth0 hardware mac address? I am pasting the network interfaces file here.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo eth0 eth1 bond0

iface lo inet loopback

##### bond0-slaves
iface eth0 inet manual
bond-master bond0
bond-primary eth0

iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

##### bond-interface
iface bond0 inet dhcp
        bond-mode active-backup
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-slaves none# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo eth0 eth1 bond0

iface lo inet loopback

##### bond0-slaves
iface eth0 inet manual
bond-master bond0
bond-primary eth0

iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

##### bond-interface
iface bond0 inet dhcp
        bond-mode active-backup
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-slaves none
```

In Proxmox, I use "bridge-hw eth0" and it works there normally, but not in Ubuntu OS.
I have found it "hwaddress ether <MAC_address_of_eth0>", but we don't want to use it.
Is there any other way for it?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello. Can someone help me to solve it? Thanks.